# How to get user input passed to params in axios get

Tags: reactjs, parameters, axios, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass what a user would select from a selection to the params in my axios GET. Here is what I have:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/url-here/', {
        params: {
            value1: submitted
        }
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error('err', err);
    });
}, []);
```

Here is my select:

```
const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState('');

<FormControl>
    <InputLabel id="submitted-select-label">Submitted</InputLabel>
    <Select
        labelId="submitted-select-label"
        id="submitted-select"
        value={submitted}
        onChange{e => setSubmitted(e.target.value)}
        input{<InputBase />}
    >
        <MenuItem value="submitted">Submitted</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value="failed">Failed</MenuItem>
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing here?

Comment: The param is coming up undefined in the console. I'm not sure what I'm missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have defined the `useEffect` and passed the function, the closure it is basically stale. The value of `submitted` might change outside, but it will not affect the value inside of the function.

You need to reload the value inside `useEffect` with the second argument:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/url-here/', {
        params: {
            value1: submitted
        }
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error('err', err);
    });
}, [submitted]);
```